# Sending email using amazon server east1 with C# doesn't work

Tags: c#, email, vbscript, smtp, telnet

I have got an old application which sends some emails with vb script as follows:

```
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Test Auto Email 20 Min Cycle Completed"
myMail.From="registers@mysite.com"
myMail.To="mehdi@mysite.com"
myMail.TextBody="Auto Email 20 Min Cycle Completed"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "username"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
myMail.Send
Set myMail = nothing
```

Now I am converting this code to C# and here is what I wrote which doesn't work:

```
using (var smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", 465))
{
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtpClient.Credentials = new system.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    smtpClient.Timeout = 10000;
    smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtpClient.Send("registers@mysite.com", "mehdi@mysite.com", "Test" , "Test");
}
```

I also tried to connect to the amazon server using Telnet which was unsuccessful. The weird thing is that when I run the script it sends the email.

Thanks

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: all the URLs: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable"

Comment: That is weird... I haven't tried it before but, as I mentioned the script is working fine and sends the emails!